# Pass parameters in Copy activity for input file in Azure data factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I need to copy data from SFTP folder and need to dynamically pick only the current date minus 1 day file. I need to load this data to ADLS Gen -1. I'm using Copy activity and have parameterised the File path and File name in Dataset and pass these values from Pipeline.

File path - xyz/test
File name - @concat('auto-miles-per-gallon',formatDateTime(addDays(utcnow(),-1),'yyyyMMdd'),'.csv').

I'm able to run the copy activity but its not copying only the specified file (auto-miles-per-gallon20191008.csv). It copies all the files available in the SFTP folder.

Files available in the folder
auto-miles-per-gallon20191008.csv
auto-miles-per-gallon20191009.csv

Attached the parameters screenshot from Dataset,Pipeline.[image: Dataset parameter[![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1g5CJ.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked `File name - @concat('auto-miles-per-gallon',formatDateTime(addDays(utcnow(),-1),'yyyyMMdd'),'.csv')`,it is right. I notice that the statements in the SFTP dataset [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-sftp#dataset-properties):

[image]

I suggest you configuring the dynamic content for filePath and fileName in the copy activity and try again.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Jay.  Wild card folder path by default was set as *.* and because of it all the files were getting selected..

Comment: @ArunS So, have you configured the folder path again to remove `.`? Does the activity works now?

Comment: @ArunS You're welcome. If you don't mind, would you please accept the answer for others' reference. Thanks.